# Save multiselected values yii2 in kartik widget

Tags: php, arrays, string, yii2, widget

I'm trying to do multiselect with kartik multiselect widget in yii2 in the form 
my $data variable is getting an array of strings

```
<? $data = ArrayHelper::map(pupil::find()->all(),'pupilId','firstname'); ?>
 var_dump($data) = array(6) { [1]=> string(5) "rotem" [3]=> string(3) "ttt" [6]=> string(12) "tom wininger" [7]
```

i'm saving it to db by before save method and implode as string of id's but when i'm trying to see it in  my view i'm getting all the pupils not just the chosen one

what method can i write that will take only the pupils the were chosen and will show it in my view file like in db but as names

[image: this is what i'm saving into db (id's of pupils that were chosen)]

[image: this is what i'm getting (all the pupils not just chosen ones)]

Answer (score 0):

I have similar thing so I know how to handle this but since you haven't provided your variables and how your method looks like, I'll write some random one.

Let's say, you're dumping `$data` and you get:

```
array(3) {
    [1]=> string(5) "rotem"
    [3]=> string(3) "ttt"
    [6]=> string(12) "tom wininger"
}
```

Then:

```
foreach($data as $dat) {
    // Do your operators here, for example:
    echo $dat.'<br>';
}
```

This will print each variable in a new line:

```
rotem
ttt
tom wininger
```

Comment: because i need the variable that is in the widget

Comment: will enter as string

Comment: @TomWininger I would like to get some more clarification: do you want to get that array from widget or insert into widget?

Comment: i wanted to save multiple values and show them in view and index so i found a solution for saving them by adding before save method and implode the array into string so now i'm getting this string if id's 1,2,4,5 but i don't know how to show the names instead of id's in view

Comment: Can you give me what you get with var_dump (either screenshot or in formatted code)?

Comment: i edit the question to be more accurate hope it will help to understand better